# Why isn't my navigation bar working?

Tags: html, css

I have used a template for my navigation bar and I'm not quite sure where I gone wrong. Can you please correct my code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Ryan$ /Users/Ryan/Downloads/logo.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <!-- Title -->
    <script>
      /*
        Creating an error page
        1. Get error code using XMLGetHTTPRequest
        2. Take them to the error page if the website is not found (if the error code is 404)
        3. If the website URL... is fine, execute all of the javascript
        Checking if javascript is enabled or installed
        1. Get the element by id (noscript)
        2. If noscript="true", make an alert warning that tells the user that the website may not function properly if you don't enable their Javascript.
        Creating a slideshow of images
        1. Enable JQuery
        2. Store your slideshow images in variables
        3. Make a variable that will store the amount of time each image will take to cycle (use setInterval)
        4. Make a for function that will slide the images every time the timer reaches a multiple of the variable in number 3.
      */
    </script>
    <style>
      /* 
        Make the whole page have a font of Open Sans. Also, add a margin of 40px
        Colour the right column gainsboro and the sidebar white
        Make the blog title bold, underlined and big (Remember to make it stand out)
        Another alternative for the blog title is just an image. In that case, you should:
        Make it repeat horizontally (X) and if the image doesn't have word in it, use figcaption
        Then, make a sidebar by making a border-right that is 1px wide and float it right of the sidebar (Also set the display to relative or fixed)
        , use a template to design the navigation menu (Make sure it's a drop down navigation menu)
      */
   #cssmenu ul,#cssmenu li,#cssmenu span,#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
   }

   #cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#fff),color-stop(100%,#fff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #db000b;
  width: auto;
   }

   #cssmenu:after,#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
   }

   #cssmenu a {
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#fff),color-stop(100%,#fff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#fff 100%);
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
   }

   #cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
   }

   #cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
   }

   #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
   }

   #cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #db000b;
  margin-left: -10px;
   }

   #cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
   }

   #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #d9d9d9;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #d9d9d9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #d9d9d9;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#fff),color-stop(100%,#f2f2f2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#f2f2f2 100%);
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #db000b;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0f1b;
  font-size: 11px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #a80008;
   }

   #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
   }

   #cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #a80008;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0f1b;
   }

   #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #8f0007;
   }

   #cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
   }
      /*
        Style the text however you want and either float it left or center it in the right column
        If you want to add images, try to save as much space as you can by making a slideshow of images
        Style the top of page button so it looks big, stands out and look fancy
        (Optional) Make a thick, black footer that will contain the top of page button
        (Optional) Style the horizontal rules (hrs) so that they have a different colour or a different style (like dotted)
      */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 <!-- Remember to:
   Try and label every section with a div (It'll come in handy!)
   Not include old code like align
   Try not to make code lines too long
   Have everything on one page except for the error page
   Separate each section off with a horizontal rule (hr)
 -->
 <!-- Checking if javascript is enabled or installed
   1. Add a no script element 
   2. Give it an id
   3. The javascript will then send a alert to tell you that you should enable/install Javascript on your browser
 -->
 <!-- Blog title goes here Navigation menu content (Brings user to a different part of the page)
      Home  
      About me > Introduction,
   About me > What it's like to be me,
   About me > Kind words,
   About me > Good moments,
   About me > Bad moments
   About me > Why I love programming so much,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Introduction,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > HTML,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > CSS,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Javascript,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Creating a website,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Tutorials > Introduction,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Tutorials > HTML,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Tutorials > CSS,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Tutorials > Javascript,
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Projects (Coming soon),
   Quotes > Famous quotes from famous people,
   Quotes > Quotes from my friends and family,
   Quotes > Quotes from me,
   The past, present and future > This website > Future,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > Introduction,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2005,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2006,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2007,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2008,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2009,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2010,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2011,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2012,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2013,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2014,
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2015,
   The past, present and future > Me > Present,
   The past, present and future > Me > Future,
   The past, present and future > Me > Brief Recap,
   Minigamez (Coming soon),
   Contact,
   Chat room
 -->
 <div id="cssmenu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="MyBlog.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span>About me</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>What it's like to be me</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Kind words</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Good moments</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Bad moments</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Why I love programming so much</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span>Web design tips 'n' tricks</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>HTML</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>CSS</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Javascript</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Building websites</span></a></li>
            <li class="has-sub"><span>Tutorials</span></a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>HTML</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>CSS</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Javascript</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Projects (Coming Soon!)</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><span>Quotes</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Quotes from Famous people</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Quotes from my friends/family</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Quotes from me</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><span>The past and future</span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>The future of this website</span></a></li>
                <li class="has-sub"><span>Me</span></li>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2005</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2006</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2007</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2008</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2009</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2010</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2011</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2012</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2013</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2014</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>2015</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Mingamez (Coming Soon)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Chat room</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 <!-- Sidebar
   Search bar from Google
   Top trending blog posts today (Top ten)
   Recent blog posts
 -->
 <!-- Articles
   Home 
   About me > Introduction 
   About me > What it's like to be me 
   About me > Kind words 
   About me > Good moments 
   About me > Bad moments 
   About me > Why I love programming so much 
   Web design tips 'n' tricks (Medium) 
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Introduction (Tiny)
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Tutorials > HTML 
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Tutorials > CSS 
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Tutorials > Javascript 
   Web design tips 'n' tricks > Projects (Coming soon) 
   Quotes > Famous quotes from famous people 
   Quotes > Quotes from my friends and family 
   Quotes > Quotes from me 
   The past, present and future > This website > Future 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > Introduction 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2005 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2006 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2007 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2008 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2009 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2010 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2011 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2012 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2013 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2014 
   The past, present and future > Me > Past > 2015 
   The past, present and future > Me > Present 
   The past, present and future > Me > Future 
   The past, present and future > Me > Brief Recap 
   Minigamez (Coming soon) 
   Contact 
   Chat room
 -->
 <!-- Top of page button -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully it is not a major mistake because I spent hours working on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error on the item "About me", it should be:

```
<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>About me</span></a>
```

And "Web design tips 'n' tricks":

```
<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Web design tips 'n' tricks</span></a>
```

The same for subitems: "Tutorials", "Quotes" and "The past and future"

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u54hr8xz/1/